# How to fix "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Android resource linking failed"[Android/Flutter]

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

It happened out of nowhere. One day I was running my code which was working just fine, and the next day, without touching my build.gradle files or any other build files this error popped up.

I have tried a lot of different solutions like changing my buildToolsVersion or setting a specific flag of AAPT(can't remember which) to false. Nothing works.
My app\build.gradle file:

```
 android {
 compileSdkVersion 27
 buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

 sourceSets {
     main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
 } 

 lintOptions {
     disable 'InvalidPackage'
 }

 defaultConfig {
     // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
     (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
     applicationId "com.skydevs.bookx"
     minSdkVersion 16
     targetSdkVersion 27
     versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
     versionName flutterVersionName
     testInstrumentationRunner 
     "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

 buildTypes {
     release {
         // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
         // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` 
         works.
         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
     }
 }
 }

 flutter {
     source '../..'
 }

 dependencies {
   implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Android resource linking failed
  Output:  C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:905: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:905: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\baada\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a5cc63922d025d4315a498efa486650c\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\baada\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.bookx\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\Users\baada\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-1.0.2.aar\aa44270b14856bd5a0b17a3c0a45cb34\res\values-v28\values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-v28\values-v28.xml:11: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.

  C:\Users\baada\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\bc8b94f938baa5558925fd51b49cb6bf\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

  C:\Users\baada\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\core-1.0.1.aar\bc8b94f938baa5558925fd51b49cb6bf\res\values\values.xml:89:5-125:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\baada\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\a5cc63922d025d4315a498efa486650c\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
          C:\Users\baada\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-27\android.jar\
          --manifest\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
          -o\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
          -R\
          @C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
          --auto-add-overlay\
          --java\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
          --custom-package\
          com.example.bookx\
          -0\
          apk\
          --output-text-symbols\
          C:\Users\baada\AndroidStudioProjects\bookx\build\app\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
          --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Comment: I'm getting a similar issue. Did you also recently upgraded some flutter packages?

Comment: i just fixed the similar issue ==> https://stackoverflow.com/a/71146453/13698241

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Today, I got the same error at my project which I was working on yesterday without any problem.

Some upgrade causes this error IMO, my solution is:

- Open the project via Android Studio
- Open `android/build.gradle` and `android/app/build.gradle`
- Just correct things what IDE warns about, it usually warns your SDK, Kotlin and Gradle versions etc.

It's not mandatory but you can check your .bashrc exports or environment variables, sometimes it can fix some problems.

Edit: When you are updating your SDK versions, don't forget to upgrade also your project dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answare. There was many post like this but none with such accurated answare.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on android emulator API level you are using.

In my case I used android emulator API **30**, but `compileSdkVersion` was **`28`**, so i got the error! By updating `compileSdkVersion` to **`30`**, everything worked correctly!

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Android emulator API 30
Dart 2.10.2
Flutter 1.22.2

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error while using flutter, but in my case the problem was caused by an incorrect line in a file in the 'res' folder in my Adroid projects.

You need to check your code, in my case it was calling a resource that doesn't exist in my android / app / src / main / res / launcher / drawable / launch_background.xml file, make sure all your resources and xml files are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check your strings.xml and It should be like:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">App Name here</string>
    <string name="facebook_app_id">2206883509627625</string>
    <string name="fb_login_protocol_scheme">fb2206883509627625</string>
</resources>
```

Special attention to add this line:

```js
    <string name="app_name">App Name here</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

check that
[How to fix "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Android resource linking failed"[Android/Flutter]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152209/how-to-fix-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-android-re/65654745)

I had the same error while using flutter, but in my case the problem was caused by an incorrect line in a file in the 'res' folder in my Adroid projects.

You need to check your code, in my case it was calling a resource that doesn't exist in my android / app / src / main / res / launcher / drawable / launch_background.xml file, make sure all your resources and xml files are ok.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, run your flutter project in Android Studio rather than Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\DELL Precision\StudioProjects\Tictactoe\build\app\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:17: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.example.tictactoe:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.
> error: failed processing manifest.

In my case I Just changed my all appicon name to ic_launcher       while generating from appicon.co

and it  doesn't show any error  now that ic_launcher file is missing.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you are connected to the Internet and rebuild the project. That solves the problem for me.