# AndroidX incompatibility error for image_picker_saver error

Tags: image, flutter, androidx

During the run console, the image_picker_saver package is giving AndroidX incompability.
the package is -   image_picker_saver: ^0.1.0

Can anyone help how to handle this error?

Run console -

```
                                   ^
      symbol: variable ActivityCompat
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker_saver-0.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepickersaver\ImagePickerDelegate.java:139: error: cannot find symbol
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{permissionName}, requestCode);
                            ^
      symbol: variable ActivityCompat
    C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image_picker_saver-0.1.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\imagepickersaver\ImagePickerDelegate.java:151: error: cannot find symbol
                            return FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, fileProviderName, file);
                                   ^
      symbol: variable FileProvider
    20 errors

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':image_picker_saver:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

    BUILD FAILED in 1m 36s
    *******************************************************************************************
    The Gradle failure may have been because of AndroidX incompatibilities in this Flutter app.
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to enable AndroidX.

Official docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility

As you see in third entry:

In android/gradle.properties, append =>

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

If you don't want to use AndroidX, latest version of packages you can use listed down below.

If your package don't listed there, enabling AndroidX is only choice.

Also change your minimum sdk inside android/app/gradle.build:

```
    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_testing"
        minSdkVersion 16 // => Make this 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

And finally, follow that answer:

[How to fix "Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. > Android resource linking failed"[Android/Flutter]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152209/how-to-fix-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-android-re/54377766#54377766)

Change the gradle version also.

Comment: The error still remains on first run but not on hot restart

Comment: @AzhanKhan I changed the answer try again.

Comment: I changed everything according to the official document and even your recommendations but the error still exists

Comment: @AzhanKhan So, it's package problem and it's already not up to date. Btw I forgot to indicate where to change minimum SDK version inside, check it again.

Comment: @AzhanKhan lastly, try 'flutter clean' terminal command, clean the project and re-run, if still not working, don't use that package so, as I said it's a bit outdated already.

Comment: I changed the min. sdk to 21 in app>build.gradle but the error remains.I changed the configurations as the official documentation too...

Comment: What are the alternatives to download image then?

Comment: @AzhanKhan be careful about official docs, because there are instructions for both enabling and disabling the AndroidX. But if it's not working after all, create another question for your specific needs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56220675/is-there-an-alternative-to-image-picker-saver-dependency

Answer (score 0):

image_picker_saver hava upgraded to 0.3.0 and support Android X