# Is there an alternative to image_picker_saver dependency

Tags: image, flutter, download

I am working on a code to download image in the device but there are androidx incompatibilities with image_picker_saver dependency.So can anyone suggest an alternative for it?

```
The complete code-
     _saveImage(imageNames) async {
await PermissionHandler()
    .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.storage)
    .then((status) async {
  if (status == PermissionStatus.denied ||
      status == PermissionStatus.disabled ||
      status == PermissionStatus.unknown) {
    await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
        [PermissionGroup.storage]).then((status1) async {
      if (status1.containsValue(PermissionStatus.granted)) {
        await get(imageNames).then((res) async {
          await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: res.bodyBytes)
              .then((str) {
            File.fromUri(Uri.file(str));
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "Saved to gallery!",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                timeInSecForIos: 1,
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 15.0);
          });
        });
      }
    });
  } else if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
    await get(imageNames).then((res) async {
      await ImagePickerSaver.saveFile(fileData: res.bodyBytes).then((str) {
        File.fromUri(Uri.file(str));
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Saved to gallery!",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIos: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 15.0);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

}

Comment: Simply, what you are trying to do is, downloading an image and saving it to a file?

Comment: Yes, downloading image and saving in downloads folder.

Comment: Only problem is accessing to Downloads folder. If we can find a way, rest of them is easy. If saving into application directory is ok for you, it's easy.

Comment: saving in application directory won't be a problem

Comment: I'll share full code later, now I'm a bit busy but for quick answer look at those packages:
https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_imag - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager ...

Comment: How long will it take?

Comment: I'm working full-time, few hours later I'll look at it.

Comment: you can simply download the image by using dio package

Answer (score 0):

You need a package for decoding/encoding algorithms. I suggest this canonicalized package:
https://pub.dev/packages/image

We will use it.

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:image/image.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

We need bodyBytes for writing file from network image file:

```
Future<dynamic> downloadImage() async =>
    await http.get(url).then((response) => response.bodyBytes);
```

Get application working directory:

```
Future<String> createDir() async =>
    await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory().then((dir) => dir.path);
```

First, we will create [Image] type variable, which is provided by image package then we will convert it to a file both decoding and encoding provided by image package again:

```
Future<io.File> writeFile(String path, var bodyBytes, String fileName) async {
  Image image = decodeImage(bodyBytes);
  io.File file = io.File(join(path, fileName));
  file.writeAsBytesSync(encodePng(image));
  return file;
}
```

So, you created your files, you need to load them, this is the method you need(You can use restored images by [Image.file] widget):

```
Future<List<io.File>> loadFiles() async {
  List<io.File> images = <io.File>[];
  final io.Directory dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  print('path: ${dir.path}');
  for (io.FileSystemEntity f in dir.listSync()) {
    if (f is io.File) {
      if (f.path.contains('.jpg')) { //any format you want
        images.add(f);
      }
    }
  }
  return images;
}
```