# Android studio error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I'm developing a Flutter application in Dart using Android Studio, but when I run my code I get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: ziparchive W 04-02 18:41:27 12204 10168 Zip: Entry at offset zero has invalid LFH signature 0
     error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

EDIT: I didn't paste my code since that it is just for testing and I'm pretty sure that the problem is in Android Studio, by the way it is here:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main()
{
  runApp(App());
}


class App extends StatelessWidget
{

  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tutorial 1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Homepage(),
    );
  }
}


class Homepage extends StatelessWidget
{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Text('test');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Updating `Gradle`, `Kotlin`, `Flutter`, `Dart`

Updating `Android Studio`

Clearing `Android Studio Cache`

running "`flutter pub get`" in project terminal

Make sure use device with same API level to that mentioned in `"app/build.grade"`

Or check this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-execution-failed-appprocessdebugresources-in-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

This problem may caused from `xml` code content:

```
1.Check activity`_main.xml` for all errors,

2. Fix all errors than rebuild by going to menu->build than click on 'Rebuild Project'
```

Or
It can be solved by updating the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` to  latest one.

[Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54152209/how-to-fix-execution-failed-for-task-appprocessdebugresources-android-re/54377766)

Answer (score 0):

In your gradle file (the one in the android/app directory), set your compileSdk version to 31. This works for me.